# How to analitacally solve system containing ">" in Math.Net Symbolics?

Tags: c#, math.net, mathdotnet-symbolics

I need to evaluate what simplifies to:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MathNet.Symbolics;

namespace GtEq {
    static class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            var eq = Infix.ParseOrThrow("a > b");
            var result = Evaluate.Evaluate(new Dictionary<string, FloatingPoint>() {
                {"a", 5.0},
                {"b", 1.0}
            }, eq);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And it throws on parser line not getting what ">" means.
[image]
I wonder if there is a comon way to expand MathNet.Symbolics for it to support "> < >= <=" operations?